# Convert pandas dataframe to a column-based order list

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert pandas dataframe into a list.
For example, I have a dataframe like below, and I want to make list with all columns.

Dataframe (df)

```
A    B    C
0    4    8
1    5    9
2    6    10
3    7    11
```

Expected result

```
[[0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9,10,11]]
```

If I use df.values.tolist(), it will return in row-based order list like below.

```
[[0,4,8], [1,5,9], [2,6,10], [3,7,11]]
```

It is possible to transpose the dataframe, but I want to know whether there are better solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think simpliest is transpose.

Use [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) or [`numpy.ndarray.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html):

```
df1 = df.T.values.tolist()
print (df1)
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.values.transpose().tolist()
print (df1)
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

Another answer with list comprehension, thank you [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623578/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-a-column-based-order-list/44623602?noredirect=1#comment76235287_44623602):

```
L = [df[x].tolist() for x in df.columns]
```

Comment: I didn't know about the 'T' function, but it seems to offer very simple transpose(I thought that I need to use zip for transpose). Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I like this function, because very short ;)

Comment: I'd normally use the above options aswell. Just incase you're looking for another, you could `[df[x].tolist() for x in df.columns]`